# Memcache lifetime

Tags: memcached, lifetime

I read a article that using memcache for caching the passwords stored in the mysql database with a certain lifetime, but when a user's password was updated in the database,memcache still cache the old data,after the lifetime is over,fetching data from database again, then got the newest data.

Any other way to get the newest updated data immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the framework you use in your app let's you set up rules, such as:

- How long to keep data in memcache / when to flush a record from cache
- How / in what circumstances to go to the db

One approach, of course, is that in the routine that updates the pw in the db, that same routine expires the relevant record in memcache.